# I am not able to show session variables as parameters in iframe Drupal 7

Tags: php, session, iframe, drupal-7

I am trying to get values from session variables while passing parameters to iframe but i am not able to get the value saved in the session mail variable .I am using drupal 7 iframe module.
Here is my code.....

```
      <iframe id="if1" width="100%" height="254" style="visibility:visible"
      src="http://www.w3schools.com/?mail=<?php echo $_SESSION['mail']; ?>" >
      </iframe>
```

Comment: What does `print_r($_SESSION);` say?

Comment: it shows all the values saved in session

Comment: if you can please help me in this issue.... @Huelfe

Comment: Are you using `session_start();`?

Comment: where do i have to write this i am new to drupal....and i am using i frame module

Comment: How do you set **$_SESSION['mail'];** variable. **session_start();** will give warning that session has already started.